# Limited Amount of Lords in a Castle?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

Whenever I host a feast and all of my lords attend it, there's always a limit to how many of them are actually visible in the castle. Instead of other lords, some random wives show up, which is pretty useless to me. I'd like to know how to bypass that limit or at least let everyone in and keep the ladies outside, so I can improve my relation with each one of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the number of visible lords may depend on the feast location.

Comment: Mind explaining any further?

Comment: some castles/towns seem to have a much larger halls so they may have more npcs.  this is just a guess though.

Answer (score 3):

Circumventing this limit is rather tedious and requires you to manually add more spots for the lords to stand in in the castle/city halls' configuration files. The lords stand at pre-determined spots, and when there aren't enough spots left, the rest of the lords are omitted from showing up. Exiting and re-entering the town shuffles which lords show up on visually on the feast, though it would take quite some exiting/reentering to greet every single lord in attendance.

Some castles and cities do have larger halls, allowing more lords to visibly attend. Which ones are the larger ones I am unsure, but the Nord have the largest **I** can recall at least.